# How to use one github repository as a vendor library, with file overrides from my own repository

Tags: php, git, github

I am using the Fuel PHP SDK for Marketing Cloud and there are some changes I'd like to make. Since I am also using Heroku, the repository is refreshed on every git push I make.

I need to modify a few files, but since the repo is refreshed on every push, my changes will get overwritten. Is there a way to copy these files into my own repo, declare that as a dependency *after* the other repo, and override the files in the main repo with my updated files?

For example, the file I want to update is named ET_Get.php. I could update it directly, but then it will be overwritten on every push. I want to duplicate that file out, make some changes, and I want the repo to use *that* file, *not* the repo's own file.

My composer.json looks like this

```
{
    "require": {
        "salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php": "1.3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "php": "7.1.28",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "twig/twig": "^2.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt":">=5.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
      "FuelSdk\\": "custom-classes",
      "Pardot\\": "custom-classes"
      }
    }
}
```

So I was thinking I could just create my own repo after the salesforce-mc repo, and have my files override those.

```
{
    "require": {
        "salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php": "1.3.0",
        "salesforce-mc/custom": "1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "php": "7.1.28",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "twig/twig": "^2.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt":">=5.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
      "FuelSdk\\": "custom-classes",
      "Pardot\\": "custom-classes"
      }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? It doesn't have to be a separate repo. Any way that I can simply have my own overrides would be fine.

I know I could fork the repo, and use my fork as a dependency, but that seems like overkill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be exactly what I needed.

https://mnapoli.fr/overriding-dependencies-with-composer/

[Use forked repo on github via composer as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147714/use-forked-repo-on-github-via-composer-as-dependency)

All I had to do was fork the original repo, make my changes, then use my repo in the composer.json like below:

```
{
    "require": {
        "salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php": "1.3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "php": "7.1.28",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "twig/twig": "^2.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt":">=5.0.0"
    },
    "repositories":[
      {
        "type":"git",
        "url": "https://github.com/user/forked-project.git"
      }
    ],
    "autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
      "FuelSdk\\": "custom-classes",
      "Pardot\\": "custom-classes"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the call server side using a library such as [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Which will work fine if it's an API that responds with some json or xml.

If their page renders something like a html thank you page, you would have to parse that to ensure it worked and then render your own.

If that's the case and you are making a GET call to ExactTargets site, then you could probably just do a header redirect.

If you do have to POST data, then you could also render a new form that is just a "Submit" button, that contains all the data in hidden fields.  It would basically be the same as if you submitted to them to begin with.

Hope that helps