# Use forked repo on github via composer as dependency

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I have a project that uses ***socalnick/scn-social-auth-doctrine-orm***. This module further depends upon:

1. ***socialnick/scn-social-auth***

Which further depends upon

2. ***hybridauth/hybridauth***

So ***ORM*** Depends on->***Social-Auth*** which depends on->***Hybrid***

In order for my application to work, I required some changes in these two modules (1) and (2). I forked these modules to my git account and made changes as per my requirement. In my application composer.json I am just putting ***socalnick/scn-social-auth-doctrine-orm*** as requirement.

How can I manage composer.json so that ***socalnick/scn-social-auth-doctrine-orm*** get my forked modules instead of default modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override that dependencies in your `composer.json`.

```json
{
    "require": {
        "socalnick/scn-social-auth-doctrine-orm": "*",
        "socialnick/scn-social-auth": "*",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/USER/scn-social-auth.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/USER/hybridauth.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your fork you could add a tag that matches the requirements of the main package, or use a branch with a version number alias:

```
"socialnick/scn-social-auth": "dev-mybranch as 2.1.0",
```

[Reference blog post from mnapoli](http://mnapoli.fr/overriding-dependencies-with-composer/)

Comment: Thanks and for others this mnapoli blog post is really helpful,